# How can I return float[] array from inside loop in Java and then call it from other methods/ classes?

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
public float dec() {

    float[] arr = new float[256];
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = r.nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
        System.out.println(arr[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will print the right data only in the for loop, but I need to call it in other places, How can I return the full list ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare float array as the return type. Then return your float array.

```java
public float[] dec() {            // Declare return type as float array. 
    float[] arr = new float[256];
    …
    return arr ;                  // Return your float array. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the return type to `float[]` and return `arr` at the end of the method. It's also a good idea to remove the `println` statement, since it adds extra overhead to the method and can be done by the caller if needed.

```
public float[] dec() {
    float[] arr = new float[256];
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = r.nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: When returning it, I'd leave the printing out of the method (it can easily done outside, if desired).

Comment: I agree, but I decided to answer with the minimal amount of change from the original code needed to answer the question. It's definitely a good idea to remove the `println` as well. I'll edit. Thanks.

Comment: When I call it I get:   "[F@4450d156"   Why I can't call and get the list ? also I agree about the printing, it was only meant to check the right data is printed.

Comment: Eyal, that looks like the result of calling `toString` on an `Array`. If you are calling `System.out.println(arr)`, you'll see that result, but that's just the way arrays are printed, and doesn't reflect the contents of the array. If you iterate through the returned array, you should see the values you expect.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
return 0;
```

Use the returned value you want.

```
return arr;
```

And also change the method type to array

```
public float[] dec()
```

However I rewrite it to a simple program to know that it's actually working, I don't change anything and of course it works.

```
public class Answer {
public float[] dec() {

    float[] arr = new float[256];
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = r.nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
       // System.out.println(arr[i]);

    }
    return arr;
}
//Just for testing purposes
public static void main(String args[]) {

   float ans = new float[256];
    Answer a1 = new Answer ();
    ans = a1.dec();
    //Let try to print the first value

    System.out.println(ans[0]);

}

}
```

Comment: That's insufficient, they also need to change the return type from `float` to `float[]`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad.

Comment: Still, the point was to call this method to get the full list, when I call it I get:  [F@4450d156

Comment: Ooh, it's returning the reference value instead of list, let me try and work on that now.

Comment: I think it's because you try printing the entire value, that's why you get the reference value.

Comment: Perfect! now I have what I need. thanks for everyone, @Muhammad -- you are the best:)

Comment: You're welcome, by the way there is no best, just trying to be

Comment: And if I want to declare the list as global variable and call it from other methods ? and to get the full list ? How can I do that ?